# Where to add while-loop to get min and max to work correctly

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop

My issue is not knowing how to properly configure this section of coding to get the max and min to work properly.

> "For the max/min logic to work correctly, it had to be placed WITHIN a
>   loop, not after it. Due to that, a WHILE loop would have been
>   preferred. (Or use correctly the max() and min() methods.)"

I have tried moving the `if` statements that include the max and min statements around to no avail. Python 3.7.3, using IDLE.

```
def user_grade(statistic = None):
    f = []
    for grade in range(5):
        if statistic == "max":
            print('Max: {}'.format(max(f)))
        if statistic == "min":
            print('Min: {}'.format(min(f)))
        f.append(float(input("Enter Grade (percentage): ")))

    else:       
        print('Average: {}'.format(sum(f)/len(f)))
```

**Expected Output:** (Numbers will vary depending on user input.)

```
Enter Grade (percentage): 99
Enter Grade (percentage): 98
Enter Grade (percentage): 97
Enter Grade (percentage): 96
Enter Grade (percentage): 95
Max: 99.0
Average: 97.0
None  #The 'min" should be here instead of None.
```

**Current Output:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 line 22, in <module>
    print(user_grade('max'))
   line 13, in user_grade
    print('Max: {}'.format(max(f)))
ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting an error because `f` is an empty list when it is called by `max()`,so just bring the `f.append()` part before the `max()`.

```py
def user_grade(statistic = None):
    f = []
    for grade in range(5):
        f.append(float(input("Enter Grade (percentage): ")))

    if statistic == "max":
        print('Max: {}'.format(max(f)))
    if statistic == "min":
        print('Min: {}'.format(min(f)))

    print('Average: {}'.format(sum(f)/len(f)))
```

Answer (score 1):

The code you've written implies you want:

```
def user_grade(statistic=None):
    grades = []

    for _ in range(5):
        grades.append(float(input("Enter Grade (percentage): ")))

    if statistic == "max":
        print('Max: {}'.format(max(grades)))
    elif statistic == "min":
        print('Min: {}'.format(min(grades)))
    else:
        print('Average: {}'.format(sum(grades) / len(grades)))
```

But your expected output and the quoted text imply something different:

```
def user_grade():
    maximum = 0
    minimum = 100
    total = 0

    for _ in range(5):
        grade = float(input("Enter Grade (percentage): "))

        total += grade

        if grade > maximum:
            maximum = grade

        if grade < minimum:
            minimum = grade

    print('Max: {}'.format(maximum))
    print('Average: {}'.format(total / 5))
    print('Min: {}'.format(minimum))
```

Comment: My current output is as shown below,  Enter Grade (percentage): 97
Enter Grade (percentage): 96
Enter Grade (percentage): 95
Enter Grade (percentage): 92
Enter Grade (percentage): 93
Max: 97.0
Average: 94.6
None  - I am needing to either get the minimum score to print, or replace this none with the minimum. This is where my struggle is. I have done as the answer above yours states and this is the outcome. Just still missing the minimum score. Any thoughts?